How to use explain in SPARQL queries to AWS Neptune in DBeaver
It is necessary to analyze performance and the query plan of a SPARQL query to AWS Neptune inside DBeaver CE IDE.
Neptune documentation describes explain option but it is passed inside the HTTP request.
Is there any configuration option for JDBC driver for retrieving explain information inside DBeaver or some pragma for the SPARQL query ?

There's currently no support for getting a query explain plan from within DBeaver.  You may want to open an issue in the Neptune JDBC Driver repo to see if anyone else is looking for similar: https://github.com/aws/amazon-neptune-jdbc-driver/tree/develop
